# How to update a value in a complex fhirBundle JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Given a bewildering [fhir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Healthcare_Interoperability_Resources) document like https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Notarise-gov-sg/api-notarise-healthcerts/master/test/fixtures/v2/pdt_art_with_nric_unwrapped.json

I need to update the part the JSON from `{ "id": "NRIC-FIN", "value": "S9098989Z" }` to `{ "id": "NRIC-FIN", "value": "foobar" }` and then emit the whole JSON again with that change.

I just about know how to access the value.

```
const fs = require("fs");
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync("pdt_art_with_nric_unwrapped.json");
let art = JSON.parse(rawdata);

let nric = art.fhirBundle.entry
  .flatMap((entry) => entry.resource)
  .find((entry) => entry.resourceType === "Patient")
  .identifier.find((entry) => entry.id === "NRIC-FIN").value;

console.log(nric);
```

Though I am puzzled how to update this value since it's so difficult to access. Am I missing a trick? I don't want to use regex btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be very close - why not just set `.value` using the syntax you already have...?

```
const fs = require("fs");
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync("pdt_art_with_nric_unwrapped.json");
let art = JSON.parse(rawdata);

let nric = art.fhirBundle.entry
  .flatMap((entry) => entry.resource)
  .find((entry) => entry.resourceType === "Patient")
  .identifier.find((entry) => entry.id === "NRIC-FIN").value = 'foobar';

console.dir(art.fhirBundle.entry)
```

... results in:

```
[
  {
    "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:ba7b7c8d-c509-4d9d-be4e-f99b6de29e23",
    "resource": {
      "resourceType": "Patient",
      "extension": [
        {
          "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-nationality",
          "extension": [
            {
              "url": "code",
              "valueCodeableConcept": {
                "text": "Patient Nationality",
                "coding": [
                  {
                    "system": "urn:iso:std:iso:3166",
                    "code": "SG"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "identifier": [
        {
          "id": "PPN",
          "type": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
                "code": "PPN",
                "display": "Passport Number"
              }
            ]
          },
          "value": "E7831177G"
        },
        {
          "id": "NRIC-FIN",
          "value": "foobar"
        }
      ],
      "name": [
        {
          "text": "Tan Chen Chen"
        }
      ],
      "gender": "female",
      "birthDate": "1990-01-15"
    }
  },
  {
    "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:7729970e-ab26-469f-b3e5-36a42ec24146",
    "resource": {
      "resourceType": "Observation",
      "specimen": {
        "type": "Specimen",
        "reference": "urn:uuid:0275bfaf-48fb-44e0-80cd-9c504f80e6ae"
      },
      "performer": [
        {
          "type": "Practitioner",
          "reference": "urn:uuid:3dbff0de-d4a4-4e1d-98bf-af7428b8a04b"
        },
        {
          "id": "LHP",
          "type": "Organization",
          "reference": "urn:uuid:fa2328af-4882-4eaa-8c28-66dab46950f1"
        }
      ],
      "identifier": [
        {
          "id": "ACSN",
          "type": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
                "code": "ACSN",
                "display": "Accession ID"
              }
            ]
          },
          "value": "123456789"
        }
      ],
      "category": [
        {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
              "code": "840539006",
              "display": "COVID-19"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "code": {
        "coding": [
          {
            "system": "http://loinc.org",
            "code": "97097-0",
            "display": "SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Ag [Presence] in Upper respiratory specimen by Rapid immunoassay"
          }
        ]
      },
      "valueCodeableConcept": {
        "coding": [
          {
            "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
            "code": "260385009",
            "display": "Negative"
          }
        ]
      },
      "effectiveDateTime": "2020-09-28T06:15:00Z",
      "status": "final"
    }
  },
  {
    "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:0275bfaf-48fb-44e0-80cd-9c504f80e6ae",
    "resource": {
      "resourceType": "Specimen",
      "subject": {
        "type": "Device",
        "reference": "urn:uuid:9103a5c8-5957-40f5-85a1-e6633e890777"
      },
      "type": {
        "coding": [
          {
            "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
            "code": "697989009",
            "display": "Anterior nares swab"
          }
        ]
      },
      "collection": {
        "collectedDateTime": "2020-09-27T06:15:00Z"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:3dbff0de-d4a4-4e1d-98bf-af7428b8a04b",
    "resource": {
      "resourceType": "Practitioner",
      "name": [
        {
          "text": "Dr Michael Lim"
        }
      ],
      "qualification": [
        {
          "code": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
                "code": "MCR",
                "display": "Practitioner Medicare number"
              }
            ]
          },
          "identifier": [
            {
              "id": "MCR",
              "value": "123456"
            }
          ],
          "issuer": {
            "type": "Organization",
            "reference": "urn:uuid:bc7065ee-42aa-473a-a614-afd8a7b30b1e"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:bc7065ee-42aa-473a-a614-afd8a7b30b1e",
    "resource": {
      "resourceType": "Organization",
      "name": "Ministry of Health (MOH)",
      "type": [
        {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/organization-type",
              "code": "govt",
              "display": "Government"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "contact": [
        {
          "telecom": [
            {
              "system": "url",
              "value": "https://www.moh.gov.sg"
            },
            {
              "system": "phone",
              "value": "+6563259220"
            }
          ],
          "address": {
            "type": "physical",
            "use": "work",
            "text": "Ministry of Health, 16 College Road, College of Medicine Building, Singapore 169854"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:fa2328af-4882-4eaa-8c28-66dab46950f1",
    "resource": {
      "resourceType": "Organization",
      "name": "MacRitchie Medical Clinic",
      "type": [
        {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/organization-type",
              "code": "prov",
              "display": "Healthcare Provider"
            }
          ],
          "text": "Licensed Healthcare Provider"
        }
      ],
      "contact": [
        {
          "telecom": [
            {
              "system": "url",
              "value": "https://www.macritchieclinic.com.sg"
            },
            {
              "system": "phone",
              "value": "+6561234567"
            }
          ],
          "address": {
            "type": "physical",
            "use": "work",
            "text": "MacRitchie Hospital, Thomson Road, Singapore 123000"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:9103a5c8-5957-40f5-85a1-e6633e890777",
    "resource": {
      "resourceType": "Device",
      "type": {
        "coding": [
          {
            "system": "https://covid-19-diagnostics.jrc.ec.europa.eu/devices",
            "code": "1232",
            "display": "Abbott Rapid Diagnostics, Panbio COVID-19 Ag Rapid Test"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

... clearly showing `foobar` set as you seem to desire. (Feel free to test with [this Repl.it](https://replit.com/@esqew/CumbersomeBeigeBuckets#index.js)).

To "emit the full JSON" again you would just re-stringify it:

```
let fullJSON = JSON.stringify(art);
```

Comment: I honestly didn't realise I could do a `.identifier.find((entry) => entry.id === "NRIC-FIN").value = 'foobar';` like that. I thought it was a copy of the array and I couldn't actually change the values whilst mapping around it.

Comment: In this instance, what's returned is a reference and not strictly a value/copy of the original.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of traversing the object manually you can use library like [Jsonpath](https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath):

```js
function replace() {
  data = JSON.parse(data);

  jsonpath.apply(data,
    '$.fhirBundle.entry[?(@.resource.resourceType == "Patient")].resource.identifier[?(@.id == "NRIC-FIN")].value',
    function(value) {
      document.body.innerHTML += `value=${value}<br>`;
      return 'foobar';
    });

  document.body.innerHTML += `updated JSON:<br> <pre>${JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2)}</pre`;
}


let data =
  `{
  "id": "340139b0-8e92-4ed6-a589-d54730f52963",
  "version": "pdt-healthcert-v2.0",
  "type": "ART",
  "validFrom": "2021-08-24T04:22:36.062Z",
  "fhirVersion": "4.0.1",
  "fhirBundle": {
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "type": "collection",
    "entry": [
      {
        "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:ba7b7c8d-c509-4d9d-be4e-f99b6de29e23",
        "resource": {
          "resourceType": "Patient",
          "extension": [
            {
              "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-nationality",
              "extension": [
                {
                  "url": "code",
                  "valueCodeableConcept": {
                    "text": "Patient Nationality",
                    "coding": [
                      { "system": "urn:iso:std:iso:3166", "code": "SG" }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "identifier": [
            {
              "id": "PPN",
              "type": {
                "coding": [
                  {
                    "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
                    "code": "PPN",
                    "display": "Passport Number"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "value": "E7831177G"
            },
            { "id": "NRIC-FIN", "value": "S9098989Z" }
          ],
          "name": [{ "text": "Tan Chen Chen" }],
          "gender": "female",
          "birthDate": "1990-01-15"
        }
      },
      {
        "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:0275bfaf-48fb-44e0-80cd-9c504f80e6ae",
        "resource": {
          "resourceType": "Specimen",
          "subject": {
            "type": "Device",
            "reference": "urn:uuid:9103a5c8-5957-40f5-85a1-e6633e890777"
          },
          "type": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
                "code": "697989009",
                "display": "Anterior nares swab"
              }
            ]
          },
          "collection": { "collectedDateTime": "2020-09-27T06:15:00Z" }
        }
      }     
    ]
  },
  
  "issuers": [
    {
      "id": "did:ethr:0xE39479928Cc4EfFE50774488780B9f616bd4B830",
      "revocation": { "type": "NONE" },
      "name": "SAMPLE CLINIC",
      "identityProof": {
        "type": "DNS-DID",
        "location": "donotverify.testing.verify.gov.sg",
        "key": "did:ethr:0xE39479928Cc4EfFE50774488780B9f616bd4B830#controller"
      }
    }
  ],
  "$template": {
    "name": "HEALTH_CERT",
    "type": "EMBEDDED_RENDERER",
    "url": "https://healthcert.renderer.moh.gov.sg/"
  }
}`

replace();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsonpath@1.1.1/jsonpath.min.js"></script>
```

---

If you are flat out replacing values without any other logic, and in case if you decide to use RegEx, then you can use [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```js
let data =
  `{  "identifier": [
            {
              "id": "PPN",
              "type": {
                "coding": [
                  {
                    "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
                    "code": "PPN",
                    "display": "Passport Number"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "value": "E7831177G"
            },
            { "id": "NRIC-FIN", "value": "S9098989Z" }
          ],
          "name": [{ "text": "Tan Chen Chen" }],
          "gender": "female",
          "birthDate": "1990-01-15"
        }
    }`

let targetId = 'NRIC-FIN';
let find = new RegExp(`(?<=${targetId}.*value":\\s*").*?(?=")`, 'ig');
data = data.replace(find, 'foobar');;
document.write(`<pre>${data}</pre>`);
```

**Note:** In the regular expression, I have used `i` flag for case insensitive search. Used `g` flag to replace all occurrences of the id. If the id is unique and there is going to be only one occurrence in entire .json file then don't use `g` flag.